# No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg0] in constructor

Tags: junit, junit5

as following code, it will throw an exception org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg0] in constructor [public xx.xx.ParameterizedTestExample(int)].

```java
@DisplayName("Parameterized Test Example")
public class ParameterizedTestExample {
    
    private final int value;
    
    public ParameterizedTestExample(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    @DisplayName("Test with value")
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "Test value {0}")
    @ValueSource(ints = {1, 2, 3})
    void testWithValue(int value) {
        assertEquals(this.value, value);
    }
    
    static Stream<Arguments> intProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(1),
                Arguments.of(2),
                Arguments.of(3)
        );
    }
}
```

so, junit 5 doesn't support the @ParameterizedTest annotaion inside a class with parametered constructor ?

Comment: I got the solution, you have to implement the interface ParameterResolver.

Answer (score 0):

`ParameterizedTest` is about parameterizing the test method, not the test instance.

So the answer to your question is "No, it does not."